Scraping dynamic data using Flutter
I want to scrape dynamic data using Flutter. While I can successfully retrieve static data, I am having trouble getting dynamic data. I currently use Python with Selenium and WebDriver to extract data, and now I am trying to convert this code to Flutter. Here is the Python code I used to extract data:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome()


driver.get('https://www.udemy.com/course/js-algorithms-and-data-structures-masterclass/?couponCode=ST21MT61124')

#<small class="author" itemprop="author">Marilyn Monroe</small>
element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ud-heading-lg")

print(element.text)
driver.quit() 


After conducting some research, I found a solution by using a package called WebViewPlus. Below is my code to extract dynamic data using Flutter:
WebViewPlus(
                onWebViewCreated: (controller) async {
                  _webViewController = controller;
                  await _webViewController?.loadUrl(
                      '{Put Your website Here}',
                  );
                },
                onPageFinished: (url) async {
                  await _setCountryAndScrapeData();
                },
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              ),


Here is my implemintation of function _setCountryAndScrapeData();
  Future<void> _setCountryAndScrapeData() async {
    if (_webViewController != null) {
      try {
        // Add delay if needed
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));

        final content = await _webViewController!.webViewController.runJavascriptReturningResult(
            """
          (function() {
            // Alternatively, modify the URL or use other JavaScript methods
            // Example for scraping: assuming the elementContent element is present
            let elementContent = document.querySelector('{your query}');
            if (elementContent) {
              return elementContent.innerText;
            } else {
              return 'Price element not found';
            }
          })();
          """
        );

        setState(() {
          _extractedContent = content.replaceAll('"', ''); // Remove quotes from the result
        });
      } catch (e) {
        setState(() {
          _extractedContent = 'Error: $e';
        });
      }
    }
  }


